# How to center an element (search form)?

Tags: html, css

Here's the code. How to center a search form? This form should be always at the center of the screen no matter what screen resolution is.
I tried margin: 0 auto; but it doesn't work.

Thank You.

```css
.search-p--i {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.search-p_wrap {
  text-align: center;
}
.search-form button {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.search-form input {
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4x;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-p">
  <div class="search-p_wrap">
    <h2 class="search-p_h2">Discover</h2>
    <span class="search-p--i">Hi!</span>
  </div>
  <form class="search-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter" required>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Aligning text**

Just add `text-align: center` to `form` and it is centered on all screen sizes.

> **text-align: center**
>
> This property describes how inline-level content of a block container is aligned.

```css
form {
  text-align: center; /* Add */
}

.search-p--i {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.search-p_wrap {
  text-align: center;
}
.search-form button {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.search-form input {
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4x;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-p">
  <div class="search-p_wrap">
    <h2 class="search-p_h2">Discover</h2>
    <span class="search-p--i">Hi!</span>
  </div>
  <form class="search-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter" required>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Flexbox solution(Modern):**

> **align-items: center**
>
> Items are centered in the cross-axis

*Note that in the example we are using `flex-direction: column`. otherwise just use `justify-content: center` for `flex-direction: row`*

```css
.search-p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* Cross axis alignment; simply said vertical stacking/positioning */
  align-items: center; /* Center cross-axis */
}
.search-p--i {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.search-p_wrap {
  text-align: center;
}
.search-form button {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.search-form input {
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4x;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-p">
  <div class="search-p_wrap">
    <h2 class="search-p_h2">Discover</h2>
    <span class="search-p--i">Hi!</span>
  </div>
  <form class="search-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter" required>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it ok to use text-align on a form? What about validation error? Is there any?

Comment: It is perfectly fine. I think you are worried with HTML `<center>` tag which is deprecated :)

Answer (score 3):

I like to use the new Flexbox layout to place something in the center, a good guide is here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ Although it's rather new, but it's already supported in majority browsers and it's looking to become the new standard in the next year or so.

```css
/* added new code */
.search-p {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.search-p--i {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.search-p_wrap {
  text-align: center;
}
.search-form button {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.search-form input {
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4x;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-p">
  <div class="search-p_wrap">
    <h2 class="search-p_h2">Discover</h2>
    <span class="search-p--i">Hi!</span>
  </div>
  <form class="search-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter" required>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox is actually supported by *ALL* [major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) ;)

Comment: I always use flexbox for answering but it was too simple to reply with `text-align: center` than flexbox. In future, yes this will be the first method to be used. I guess `justify-content: center` is not need in this answer since `flex-direction: column` is being applied and OP only needs horizontal centering :)

Answer (score 1):

CSS and form validation have nothing to do with each other, one is simply styling - the other is data checking which is handled either client-side by JS (bad idea without server validation) and / or server side by  (always do this) so there will be no problem. *(reacted on comment)*.

Some other problems might surface tho since `text-align: center` only works when elements are `display: inline-block` - `float: left; float: right; display: block;` will all break this center.

What I would suggest doing is adding a wrapper that will center the search in the form through means of `margin: 0 auto` - which is a much more solid way to center elements than `text-align: center` which as it says is meant for *text* (even tho I have also abused this property many many many times over).

```css
.search-p--i {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.search-p_wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Added a selector here */
.search-form .search-form-field-wrap {
  display: block; /* optional - divs are block by default. */
  width: 80%; /* or anything else */
  margin: 0 auto; /* you're gonna want to use this for centering block elements */
}

.search-form button {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.search-form input {
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4x;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
form {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-p">
  <div class="search-p_wrap">
    <h2 class="search-p_h2">Discover</h2>
    <span class="search-p--i">Hi!</span>
  </div>
  <form class="search-form">
    <!-- added a wrapper here -->
    <div class="search-form-field-wrap">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter" required>
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Made a mistake with the selector - changed it to equal the HTML class _my bad!_